# Output of auto-encoder in PyTorch shows a grid on image

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I'm working on an image reconstruction task using a convolutional auto-encoder implemented in PyTorch. The model that I'm using is the following one:

```
class Model_CAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model_CAE, self).__init__()
        self.act = nn.Hardtanh()
    
        # ENCODER
        self.e1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=0)
        self.e2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=2)
        self.e3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)

        # DECODER
        self.d1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, output_padding=0)
        self.d2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=0)
        self.d3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 3, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=0, output_padding=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        #SENZA LINEAR
        e1 = self.act(self.e1(x))
        e2 = self.act(self.e2(e1))
        e3 = self.act(self.e3(e2))
   
        d1 = self.act(self.d1(e3))
        d2 = self.act(self.d2(d1))
        out = self.act(self.d3(d2))
    
        return out

    def name(self):
        return "CAE"
```

The problem is that on the output of the network appears a sort of grid, as the sample below shows:

[image: !]

I tried to change the activation function but nothing changes. What could I do?

Comment: Could you provide the loss function you are using, as well as the dimensions of the input image?

Comment: I'm using the MSE (mean square error). The dimension of the image is 256x256.

Comment: So I am deducing the output is a 3-channel 252x252 map? I have two questions: (1) which type of interpolation do you use to scale it to your target image (the input); (2) Why is the preview given below is grayscale, and not RGB?

Comment: the image is a grayscale image (so 1 channel), then I repeat it three times, so it becomes a 3 channels image. However, it is still a grayscale image. The point is that if I show the input image (namely the grayscale repeated three times), it doesn't have the grid.

Comment: What about **q° (1)**? Also why do you repeat the channel three times for your input, and why do you output a 3-channel map at the end?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your first question. I don't use any interpolation. Given the grayscale image, I repeat that three times (with the function numpy.repeat()) and this become the input of my network and the target image. Therefore, the output of my network has to be a 3 channel image because I have to compare it to the target image that is a 3 channel. I repeat the image three times because in literature, if it is necessary to show a grayscale image in three channel the right way is to proceed in this way.

Comment: My question was how do you apply the MSE on your output and target images, they have different dimensions, correct? My other question was regarding why are you using three-channel inputs and outputs in your model, in the first place?

Comment: No, output and target images have the same dimension. Do you mean why the input has shape (batch size, 3, 256, 256 ) ? I know that the input of a model has usually a shape (N, C, H, W).

Comment: Are you sure about that? If you feed a 3-channel 256x256 map to your network, it will output a 3-channel **252x252** map. Just try the following line: `Model_CAE()(torch.rand(1, 3, 256, 256)).shape`. About the channel number, why not just simply use a single channel for input, same for output?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I got confused, I'm working on different models and the input of this specific model is (3x28x28). I could try to use a single channel for input . Do you think is that the problem?

Comment: I was following this link to implement the autoencoder: https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-implement-convolutional-autoencoder-in-pytorch-with-cuda/

Answer (score 0):

I notice two things that could lead to gridding like this: the last `TransConv` layer params of 5,2 and using `hardTanh` throughout. I saw grids when I used sigmoid throughout in an autoencoder. The final layer should indeed have such a function to normalize it to the form as with the input image, but in-between, the other layers should probably use something like `relu()` instead.

By the way, The parameters are not typical in your conv/deconv layers. Normally you'd want to preserve the size, so for a `Conv2d` layer with kernel size 5 and stride 1, use padding of 2, and so on. For `ConvTranspose2d`, conventionally kernel sz 2 and stride 2 to exactly double each spatial dim. Use conventional values as such.